Upper bounds on quotients of binomial coefficients
Let $\gamma>1$ be a real number and let $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Define $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$
$$
f(n_0) = \frac{\binom{n-n_0}{m}}{\binom{n}{m}},
$$
where
$$
m = \Big\lfloor{\frac{n}{\lceil\gamma n_0 \rceil}}\Big\rfloor.
$$
Remark: $f(n_0) = \mathbb{P}(X = 0 )$, where $X\sim\text{Hypergeometric}(n,n_0,m)$ (following the notation from Wikipedia)

Goal: I aim to find a non-trivial upper bound for $f(n_0)$. Specifically, I would like to show that there exists a constant $c=c(\gamma)<1$ such that
$$
f(n_0) < c
$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large, and $n_0 \leq n/(2\gamma)$.

Progress and Observations: Note that the following expression can be helpful
$$
f(n_0) =\frac{(n-m)\ldots(n-m-n_0+1)}{n\dots(n-n_0+1)}.
$$
Although $f$ is not necessarily increasing, I have shown that
$$
f(n_0) \leq \frac{\binom{n-n_0}{ n/\lceil\gamma n_0\rceil -1  }}{\binom{n}{n/\lceil\gamma n_0\rceil -1}} =:\tilde f(n_0),
$$
and $\tilde f$ appears to be increasing, although I have not been able to prove it.
If I could establish that $\tilde f(n_0)$ is increasing, then for $n_0 \leq n/(2\gamma)$ (assuming that it is an integer), we would get the desired result
$$
f(n_0) \leq \tilde f(n_0) \leq \tilde f(n/(2\gamma)) = 1 - \frac{1}{2\gamma}.
$$
Remark: I have numerically checked and it seems that the bound is correct (and that $c$ exists)
Questions:

Are there any known references or techniques that can help with this type of upper bound?
Is there a way to prove that $\tilde f(n_0)$ is increasing?


Your formula yields $$f(n_0)=\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{n-n_0-j}{n-j}\leqslant \left(\frac{n-n_0}{n}\right)^m=
\left(1-\frac{n_0}{n}\right)^m\leqslant e^{-mn_0/n},$$
that is about $e^{-1/\gamma}$.

After cancellations and a bit of algebra, for $t:=\gamma>1$, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
f(n_0)&=\prod_{j=0}^{n_0-1}\Big(1-\frac{m}{n-j}\Big) \\ 
&\le\exp\Big(-m\sum_{j=0}^{n_0-1}\frac1{n-j}\Big) \\ 
&\le\exp\Big(-m\int_{n-n_0+1}^{n+1}\frac{dx}x\Big) \\ 
&=\Big(1-\frac{n_0}{n+1}\Big)^m \\ 
&\le\exp\Big(-m\frac{n_0}{n+1}\Big) \\ 
&\le\exp\Big(-\Big(\frac n{(t+1)n_0}-1\Big)\frac{n_0}{n+1}\Big) \\ 
&\le\exp\Big(-\Big(\frac n{(t+1)n_0}-\frac n{2tn_0}\Big)\frac{n_0}{n+1}\Big) \\ 
&=\exp\Big(-a\frac n{n_0}\frac{n_0}{n+1}\Big)\le e^{-a/2}<1, 
\end{aligned}$$
where $a:=\frac{t-1}{2t(t+1)}>0$. $\quad\Box$
